# SQL recursive criss cross hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, hana

I have a dataset that looks like the below:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2964    | 12814   | 4       |
| 0001    | 0002    | 0       |
| 7745    | 2964    | 0       |
| 0003    | 0004    | 0       |
| 0002    | 0005    | 6       |
| 12986   | 7745    | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Essentially, what I am looking for in my desired output would be:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 12986   | 12814   | 4       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

So, essentially:

12986 JOIN on 7745 and then JOIN on 2964, to get 12814. Where ColumnC contains a value > 0.

I could do the above, but my dataset can go into the millions. So that would end up being too many joins. I have tried using HANA's hierarchy_descendants function. But I still don't get the desired result. I do get the levels, but what i would like is to use the ID in ColumnA to get to the related ID in columnB where COLUMN

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I know I tagged ***SQL Server*** and ***Hana*** but figured I could get more solutions if both are included. In terms of the desired results, please see below:

```
    +---------+---------+---------+
    | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
    +---------+---------+---------+
    | 12986   | 12814   | 4       |
    | 0001    |  0005   | 6       |
    +---------+---------+---------+
```

So we would have to go both ways.

Comment: Is this sql-server or hana. You have both tags. In SQL server you would use a recursive CTE.

Comment: Hi TomC, I'm using HANA sorry for the confusion bu5 figure I could have more solutions if I included both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using SQL Server as DBMS, then you can use such a Recursive CTE( *Common Table Expression* ) in order to bring the desired row through hierarchical steps occuring among `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` :

```
WITH t2(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, level) AS 
(
  SELECT t1.*, 1 
    FROM t1 where ColumnA = '12986'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB, t1.ColumnC, t2.level + 1
    FROM t2
    JOIN t1 on t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnB
)
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
  FROM t2
 WHERE level = (SELECT MAX(level) FROM t2);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=213049d28ec125ae7be035151a182ec9)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, this works great and produced the desired results. But in looking at the results. I would expect it would've included 0001 | 0005 | 6 as well. Let me update the desired results. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That works, the DB used is HANA and though HANA 2.0 doesnt support recursive CTE, I was able to convert the logic you used into HANA's hierarchy function. That produced the same result I was looking for. Thanks very much.